# How To Access Data of an TreeViewItem Object

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, model, treeviewitem

I build an MVVM pattern TreeView with

-Root
--Item
---Subitem

When clicking on any of the TreeViewItems, I would like to display the details of the actual Object (Model) in an separate Window.

But I'm not sure how to access the data of the object.

```
private void TreeView_OnSelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem tvi = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
    MessageBox.Show(tvi.ToString());
}
```

Comment: How are you getting on with this? Did you figure out a way to do it yourself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not recommend of using `TreeView_OnSelectedItemChanged` in `MVVM` styled `WPF` applicaiton.

Define on on your `ModelView` binded a binding to  [IsSelected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.isselected.aspx) property of `TreeeViewItem` and you wil be *always* aware of selection,a nd can select the item of interest from the code, as well.

Comment: +1 this is the approach I use. Of course, unless you're testing this property a little code behind isn't an issue.

Comment: So the individual items hold their `IsSelected` state and the `ViewModel` uses something to aggregate `IsSelected` changing in the items to figure out what has been selected?

Comment: @Simon: with databinding you populate treeview. So to every TreeViewItem associated one object, the one modelview object. If you bind treeviewitem's IsSelected property to the property of modelview, to see which item was selected by user for you it's enough to scroll over modelview objects collection and find that one with IsSelected==true.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I think it could be cumbersome picking up when selection has changed in the View's ViewModel though.

Comment: Working in this way you *completely* detach yourself from treeview UI. Let's say after 1 year you use instead of it some other very cool control, it will continue to work, without need of creating new event handlers and so on..

Answer (score 4):

My prior answer was addressing more than what was asked.

Since you want to react on selection changing in the TreeView by displaying the details of the TreeViewItem's bound object, you could use [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/)'s `Action` mechanism. You can hook up the `SelectedItemChanged` event of your TreeView to a method in your ViewModel.

For Example in your View:

```
<TreeView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding YourDataObjects}"
    cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectedItemChanged] = [Action OnSelectedItemChanged($this)]"/>
```

And in your ViewModel you will have this method:

```
public void OnSelectedItemChanged(YourDataObject selectedItem)
{
    //Do something with the selected item here 
}
```

If you have problems setting this up let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewModel, create a dependency property of type TreeViewItem, and in the View bind the SelectedValuePath property of the TreeView to your new dependency property.

Comment: You can also completely skip the ViewModel and just bind directly to 'SelectedItem' on the tree view using an ElementName binding - this is a useful option if there is some reason you can't/don't want to put a `SelectedItem` type property on your ViewModel (or if you are working with someone elses VM that you have no control over, and they haven't exposed the item) - e.g. `<MyControl ItemToView="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=myTreeViewName}" ... />`

Comment: You can't bind the `SelectedItem` property of a `TreeView`.

Comment: You can but you have to use a one-way binding because its a read only property.

Comment: `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}"` gives me the error ''SelectedItem' property is read-only and cannot be set from markup.'

Comment: You need to use OneWayToSource and the property in your VM must also be a dependency property.

Comment: So it turns out I'm completely wrong and its SelectedValuePath not SelectedItem you use: `SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=SelectedTreeItem}"` - just had to go back and look at some code to find it. Updated my answer. This property is also two way.

Comment: Could you show some example code where the ViewModel has a reference to the selected data object? I'm curious about how this would work

Answer (score 0):

In an MVVM pattern, the data associated to a a control is supposed to be in the **DataContext** dependency property.